# Azure APIM policy.xml restricted routing

Tags: xml, azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management, apim

I Have two products(APIs) within azure APIM set in 2 different subscriptions (2 different domains). Currently our apim is on premium sku and can call multiple custom domains. Depending on the environments I am deploying APIM to - I would like to add a policy that will deny the Inbound requests from all other domain's API and accept only from the one on second domain. Basically restricting all other API-1 calls on domain2. Is there a way to achieve that by adding conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing policy at API level you can make sure that it is executed for that API alone, `choose` policy allows for conditional logic, and policy expressions expose request information, so:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUri.Host == "contoso.com")">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="400" reason "Bad request"/>
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy! This gave me an idea. I am trying to variabilize "contoso.com" with something like <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUri.Host == "{{DOMAIN}}")"> and replace the variable in the condition through a powershell script like below. % { $_.Replace("{{DOMAIN}}", "contoso.com") } | When I do this I am getting an error - [Code= ValidationError, Message= 'contoso.com' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 4, position 73., Target= representation]. Any idea what's wrong with my above when condition?

Comment: Double check policy after you do the replacement. Sound like quotes are missing somewhere.